# UIImagePickerController in Landscape embedded in a UINavigationController Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode7, uiimagepickercontroller

Im trying to present the ImagePicker in Landscape with a landscape only app that embedded in UINavigationController. None of the answers I've found are working.  Apparently this is possible now. Ive found a way to do this in Swift from [here](http://cartoonsmart.com/how-to-pick-photos-from-the-camera-or-photo-library-and-use-them-in-sprite-kit-with-swift-2/), but I'm not using Swift. Perhaps someone can help me convert this Swift code to Objective-C or provide a real working example in Objective-C.  It looks like many people would benefit from this. Thanks for helping in advance.

Working Swift Code that needs converting to Objective-C:

```
//Appdelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedIntefaceOrentationForWindow window: UIWindow?) ->UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    if let presentViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        if (presentViewController.isKindOfClass(UIImagePickerController) && !presentViewController.isBeingDismissed() ) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
        }
    }
return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}
```

Objective-C Code I'm using to present the Image Picker gives a SIGBART error from the app delegate "Works fine with portrait enabled otherwise":

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
UIViewController *viewController = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[viewController presentViewController: imagePicker animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Doesn't really sound like a question. Just seems like you just don't want to do it yourself.

Comment: @rocky Or I don't know how

Comment: Read up on Swift or state the exact problem you are having.

Answer (score 4):

This is the Objective-C code.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if (([window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) && (window.rootViewController.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed == NO)) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape 
}
```

Comment: Works Perfect! @Sam Warfield.  You are Awesome!